# Problema ao instalar pacote flash do express via npm

Tags: node.js, express.js

Estou tendo dificuldade de instalar os pacotes do middleware `flash` do express. Não consigo instalar nenhum dos pacotes, tanto **flash**, **connect-flash** ou **express-flash** apresentam o seguinte erro no prompt:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe se os pacotes estão disponíveis para uso. Estou utilizando Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Olá...
Existe algum proxy na rede onde voce está?
Olhando no github do pŕoprio NPM, olha essa resposta:
https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16661#issuecomment-302770874 Valeu!

Comment: @rafakwolf Não tem proxy não man, na verdade eu consegui resolver com um **npm update** por incrível que pareça!